# Android studio 1.0 do not display drawable-hdpi , drawable-xhdpi, drawable-mdpi,drawable-xxhdpi

Tags: android-studio

When I create a new project ,my Android studio 1.0 do not display drawable-hdpi , drawable-xhdpi, drawable-mdpi and drawable-xxhdpi .
I don't konw the reason.
This is my res directory structure
|--res
  |--drawable
  |--layout
  |--menu
  |--values
Someone help？

Answer (score 25):

This is most likely because your project explorer is viewing them in Android mode. Above the folders there should be a dropdown button which you can choose to view them in Project mode. You should now be able to see the other drawable folders.

Comment: Is there any way to import images into the correct folders without switching the view mode?

Comment: When you right click on the res/drawable folder in the view hierarchy you can add an image by selecting **New > Image Asset**. A dialog will open which asks you which destination directory you wish to save that file in; i.e. drawable-mdpi.

Comment: I do not the mdpi/hdpi/xdpi/xxhdpi structure under the 'projects' tab. I could create these manually though.

Answer (score 11):

Try viewing the folders in different modes "Project" / "Android". If folders are missing you can add them easily.

1 : Right Click on "res" folder --> "New" --> "Android Resource Directory"

[image]

2 : Select resource type as "drawable" from the list

[image]

3 : Select "Density" as the Available qualifiers on the Left pane and click on the ">>" button

[image]

4 :  Select a qualifier from the Density list

[image]

That's it!

[image]

Comment: Very detailed answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Those folder will show up after you change the explorer setting to Project.

Answer (score 2):

Put your drawables-* folders in res/ directory not res/drawables
It will show all drawa