# Android studio 1.1.0 do not display drawable-hdpi , drawable-xhdpi, drawable-mdpi,drawable-xxhdpi

Tags: android-studio

I downloaded Android Studio version 1.1.0.

When I create a project, there are no drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi folders.

Same as in the other thread from December 22, 2014. That person had Android Studio 1.0 [Android studio 1.0 do not display drawable-hdpi , drawable-xhdpi, drawable-mdpi,drawable-xxhdpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598698/android-studio-1-0-do-not-display-drawable-hdpi-drawable-xhdpi-drawable-mdpi)

The only way I can those folders created is by adding a new Image Asset as suggested by Joel in that same thread.

Is this the new default behavior?

Comment: You can simply create a new resources folder.

Comment: Read Joel's answer (no the comments) again, it contains all details you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android studio 1.0 do not display drawable-hdpi , drawable-xhdpi, drawable-mdpi,drawable-xxhdpi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598698/android-studio-1-0-do-not-display-drawable-hdpi-drawable-xhdpi-drawable-mdpi)

Answer (score 0):

You can create it manually by same name in your res folder. And In Android Studio 1.2 beta 3 use mipmap for images.